# Browser Links - Nonstop Signalr Calls in MVC 5 application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, signalr

I've created a new MVC 5 Project in VS2013 and when I create the project I gave the authentication mode to none because I planned to use signalr in my project later.

I didn't install any signalr related files instead of the two signalr js files  (in my scripts folder). And there are no any startup class or OWIN.
But when I run my application there are signalr calls going and going using longpooling. These things can be viewed in the firebug console.

Previously I've used signalr with many projects using VS 2012 MVC4 this is the first time I'm using MVC5. And this slows down my application. How this could be happened. 
Here is the POST message...
[image]

[image]

Please help..

Comment: post your code also.

Comment: I didn't write any code related to signalr.. actually even if there aren't any code just a sample index page, signalr calls going

Comment: how did you install the signalR into your project?

Comment: I didn't install it. just only  copied the jquery.signalr 2.1.2.js to my script folder. And there are no any startup class or OWIN installed. Previously I've used signalr with MVC4 without any problem.

Comment: please remove the existing script files from the project and install the SignalR using nuget packages manager.

Comment: I've deleted the js files. For this project I won't need signalr so No need to install it. But the issue is still there...

Comment: which is this request URL that we can see in the POST message request in screenshot?

Comment: This seems to be Visual Studio which is using SignalR for debugging purposes - search for browserlink for mire details.

Comment: Browser Link does indeed use SignalR under the hood. It's how Visual Studio is able to update browser(s) content by simply saving files in the VS IDE, rather than having to do a full build. It's clever stuff, but if it's causing problems then you can [disable browser link](http://www.poconosystems.com/software-development/how-to-disable-browser-link-in-visual-studio-2013/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a dev tool only, it's not actually part of your application. I suggest you read [this intro](http://www.asp.net/visual-studio/overview/2013/using-browser-link) which also tells you how to disable the feature.

Comment: it will not refresh my page in production same way you mean?